# How do I take a variables prior value and subtract it from the final value if the total value of the variable cannot exceed a certain amount?

Tags: javascript

example:

```
var num = 20;
var sub = 6;
var add = 10;
num = num - sub;
num = num + add;
if (num>20){
num = 20;}
console.log("X was added to var num");
```

How can I get the console log to say that var num really only had 6 added to it before it hit it's max value?

Comment: By outputting the value of `sub`?  Perhaps this example isn't clearly demonstrating what you're trying to do...

Comment: Yeah im sorry, I'm pretty new to coding and I would take from the code I'm working on but there's several hundred lines and it would have taken a lot to have clearly shown my issue. Basically the 'sub' could have happened multiple times before at values other than 6 before the 'add' happened and I needed a way to get the total of the 'add' if it was the full 10 or somewhere in between. Again sorry for the vaugeness, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. Do you need to keep a log of what **num** is?

I would reccomend an array for that:

```
let log = [];
```

Then before you change **num**:

```
log.push(num);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

If you just want the console to display the value of a variable there's several ways:

```
console.log(add, " was added to var num");
console.log(add + " was added to var num");
console.log(`${add} X was added to var num`);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I think that will work! Thank you! As I said in my comment to David, I'm sorry for the vaugeness.